# React Native render from object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, return, fetch, render

I'm doing a simple app and I wanted to render the results from the 2nd fecth in a Text, so de user could see the exercise name, but i can log both but I can't return it in a Text. I tried to save result in a state variable but it does an infinite loop.

```
function UserPlan({route}) {
  const id = route.params.id;
  const token = route.params.token;
  //console.log(id, token);
 let myData ={}

  function getExercises() {
    fetch(`https://startdoing.herokuapp.com/user_plans/plan/${id}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        result.map((result) => {
          //console.log(result.exercises);
          result.exercises.map((data) => {
            //console.log(data.exercise_id);
            fetch(
              `https://startdoing.herokuapp.com/exercises/${data.exercise_id}`,
              {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                },
              },
            )
              .then((response) => response.json())
              .then((result) => {
                
                myData=result
                console.log(myData.exerciseName);
               /*  console.log(result);
                console.log(result.exerciseName);
                console.log(result.videoUrl); */
                
                
              })

              .catch((error) => console.log('error', error));
          });
        });
      })

      .catch((error) => console.log('error', error));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getExercises();
  });

  return(
     <>
     <Text>hello</Text>
     </>
  )
}

export default UserPlans;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// If you want to fetch the first time only, add dependencies that makes your effect run again when changes.
// In this case they are id and token

 const [exercises, setExercises] = useState([])

 useEffect(() => {
 function getExercises() {
    fetch(`https://startdoing.herokuapp.com/user_plans/plan/${id}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        result.map((result) => {
          
          Promise.all(result.exercises.map((data) => {
            
            return fetch(
              `https://startdoing.herokuapp.com/exercises/${data.exercise_id}`,
              {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                },
              },
            )
              .then((response) => response.json())
            ).then((exercises) => {
   
                setExercises(exercises)
             })
              
          });
        });
      })

      .catch((error) => console.log('error', error));
  }


    getExercises();
  }, [id, token]); // <-- Here
```

Read more https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Comment: Yes but this way just return the last value

Comment: what do you mean by last value? what do you expect?

Comment: For example I know that the exercises that exist are push ups and arm curl, if I use this method it will just return me one of them and what I expect is render both in a view so the user can see what exercises exist in that plan

Comment: @clipshot: You should use Promise.all(...) if you want to wait to all requests => set the response to state. Check out my update

Comment: ok that problem is resolved but now I have another. When I try render the array it only render the first element, but in the console.log I have 2 elements in the array!
Example code:
` return (
    <View>
      {myExcerciseData.map((data) => {

        return (
          <Text key={data._id}>
            {console.log(data.exerciseName)}
          Name: {data.exerciseName}
          </Text>
        )
      })}
    </View>
  );`

Answer (score 0):

```
    function UserPlan({route}) {
      const id = route.params.id;
      const token = route.params.token;
      //console.log(id, token);
     let myData ={}
     const [myExcerciseData, setExcerciseData] = useState(null)

    
      function getExercises() {
        fetch(`https://startdoing.herokuapp.com/user_plans/plan/${id}`, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((result) => {
            result.map((result) => {
              //console.log(result.exercises);
              result.exercises.map((data) => {
                //console.log(data.exercise_id);
                fetch(
                  `https://startdoing.herokuapp.com/exercises/${data.exercise_id}`,
                  {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                    },
                  },
                )
                  .then((response) => response.json())
                  .then((result) => {
                    
                    myData=result
                    setExcerciseData(result)
                    console.log(myData.exerciseName);
                   /*  console.log(result);
                    console.log(result.exerciseName);
                    console.log(result.videoUrl); */
                    
                    
                  })
    
                  .catch((error) => console.log('error', error));
              });
            });
          })
    
          .catch((error) => console.log('error', error));
      }
    
      useEffect(() => {
        getExercises();
      },[]); //if you pass variable here it will create infinite loop

       useEffect(() => {
        console.log("updated data")
      },[myExcerciseData]);
    
      return(
         <>
         {myExcerciseData ? 
          <Text>{myExcerciseData.exerciseName}</Text>
         :
         <Text>Loading...</Text>
         </>
      )
    }
    
    export default UserPlans;
```

This should work, please check once & revert back if got any problem

Comment: Its still looping

Comment: @clipshot can you provide a working link with code

Comment: here it is. I hardcodded the user id and token so u can test
https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-morning-dvphs?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @clipshot getting invalid token

Comment: try this eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJkYXRhIjp7ImVtYWlsIjoidGVzdGluZ0BlbWFpbC5jb20iLCJpZCI6IjVmZGQzYzZkOGE2YWNlMjg2MDE0MGUwYSIsIm5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0aW5nIn0sImlhdCI6MTYwODU1MTY4NCwiZXhwIjoxNjE1NzUxNjg0fQ.mmzPDcRnXc5ZwZnZCasQ2l3705fLQcNZA9BMV5Cc9Fw